# Async.Parallel, grouping work of many works

Tags: f#

Is a pattern like:

```
seq[ workSeq, workSeq ..., workSeq, workSeq]
|> Seq.map( Async.Parallel )
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

ok?, Or do i have to do:

```
seq[ workSeq, workSeq ..., workSeq, workSeq]
|> Seq.concat
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

How do these two options behave differently ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the question. Your first code will work, won't it?

Comment: @Dario yes but maybe Async.Parallel of a sequence of Async.Parallel is not a good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does a single fork-join among all the tiny pieces of work, whereas the other does a fork-join over a group of other fork-join batches.  Which behavior do you intend?  The former seems more likely to be useful to me... So I would probably do the concat.

Comment: Fork Join is a big black box for me (any ref would be great, note I did google it but no great details). So I don't really know. I am using this to download profile info from facebook. For each user I have to get his Music, Books and other Interests. For each user I wanted to group the download of each Category with Async.Parallel, and then run Async.Parallel over all the users I want to get data for. Thanks